# How to push deletions to local breeze caches?

Tags: breeze

If I'm using breezejs and one client deletes a record from their cache and it saves to the server, then another client comes along with that record still in their cache, how do I get the second client's cache to update and remove the record that has been hard deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question and we don't have a really great answer.  We refer to these as 'ghost' entities, and the approach we have taken to them in the past is that if you requery for an entity ( or entities) **by id**, and they are not returned then you can safely remove them from the entityManager. (The code below has not been tested, but should give you the idea);

```
function checkIfDeleted(entityManager, entities) {
  origEntities = entities.slice(0);
  var q = EntityQuery.fromEntities(entities);
  entityManager.executeQuery(q).then(function(data) {
    var foundEntities = data.entities;
    foundEntities.forEach(function(e, ix) {
      if (entities.indexOf(e)) {
        origEntities.splice(ix,1)
      }
    });
    if (origEntities.length > 0) {
      origEntities.forEach(function(e) {
        entityManager.removeEntity(e);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Curious, is there a suggestion for what to do when you're not querying by ID? Say you're querying for all the attachments on a section, and one of the attachments is now gone?

Comment: If you think about it, requerying by 'id' is really the only safe way to detect 'ghosts', everything else about an entity is mutable, so if you don't find an entity that 'matches' you don't really know if it was deleted or just modified.   However, when you query by id, if it isn't found then you KNOW that it was deleted.

Comment: Thinking about it, what's unsafe about running a query locally and remotely and comparing results? I'd remove anything in the local cache that isn't in the remote query results, and I suppose I could do the comparison by seeing which IDs are missing.

Comment: But if you find a missing id, you won't know if the entity was deleted by another user or simply changed by another user. If it was deleted you probably want to remove it from the cache, but if it was simply modified, then you want to requery it (by id) in order to get it's current values.